# How to create a facebook web application with stateless communication?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, web

I am developing a web application where i wish to achieve stateless communication between the client and the server.The server serves out a web page template to a client.Now from the client side i wish to know the identity of the user of the application so that i can print his name on the page.
Since it is a facebook app so i am not providing the option of user to login or logout through my application.

How would i be able to do it?i can not use JSP to serve dynamic web pages and also i can not use cookies.

Comment: I am using server side authentication for user permissions

Answer (score 0):

That leaves localStorage, I guess.

But I do have to wonder what the point is of said application, with only client-side state.

Comment: Once on the client side i get the uid of the client ,then i can fill the web pages with his data with webservice calls

Comment: Ah, well, then you are not really fully stateless. Anyway, you can use localStorage to save things between pages/visits. If you only need to save things temporarily sessionStorage should work.

Comment: However, if the question is really about how to implement the actual templating/insertion of data, not how to store said data without cookies/server side state (or doing the AJAX requests each pageload), this reply is not really helpful. :)